# RecyclerView scroll single row at a time

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which contains one screen full of information per record. I want to restrict user to *scroll single record at a time* and like to visualize it as if user is viewing one page at a time.

The problem is, I have create a layout of full screen size, and can populate it with data as well. But, on scrolling it gives an effect of as if I am scrolling a role, and on fast swap, it jumps multiple records as well.

I was thinking of `ViewPager`, but as records size can vary, I don't know how to use it

I have no idea how to solve this problem, please help.

Comment: Feel free to implement you own `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` which would fulfill your needs

Comment: can you please help me, what can I use to ensure that a scroll cannot move more than one record per swipe (up/down), just like view pager.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative option, instead of using a recycler view you can use this library.

https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager

It's a view pager but it has an adapter that makes it Vertical, so in that way, you'll have that behavior that you want.